# Adding multiple class for Swiper Pagination Bullet

Tags: swiper.js, react-native-swiper, ngx-swiper-wrapper

I am trying to add a new `element class` to each of my pagination bullet, and I want to retain the default style of the `swiper`. So what I did is

```
pagination={
    clickable: true,
    bulletClass: `swiper-pagination-bullet ${style['feature-pagination']}`,
}
```

I was able to get the style of `swiper-pagination-bullet` and my custom style. However, the other functionalities is not working anymore (e.g. click function, active selection)

I tried to check the code and it looks like the `swiper` is not currently handling multiple class, since this [line of code](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/master/src/components/pagination/pagination.js#L218) returns `empty` since it is only expecting a single class only.

Is there any work around for this? I like to create pull request for this, but I like to ask the community of I am missing in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Now it support multiple class with this [changes](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/pull/3913). You can add multiple class by separating them with spaces

```
pagination={
    clickable: true,
    bulletClass: `swiper-pagination-bullet ${style['feature-pagination']}`,
}
```

### Old

So I requested an [enhancement to Swiper Repository](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/3905). As of the moment, the pull request to handle `bulletClass` and `bulletActiveClass` still haven't accepted.

For the mean time, this is the best workaround for it.

```
pagination={
    clickable: true,
    bulletClass: `swiper-pagination-bullet`,
    renderBullet: (index, className) => {
    return `<span class="${className} feature-pagination"></span>`;
    }
}
```